# SharedPreferences did not work for EditText

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

My application has 2 editText.

I want to save 2 text from EditText to sharedpreferences and then load it, but when i try to load it after saving - app reads in every editText the same Text with the last EditText.

```
    private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "myPreferences";
    private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME2 = "myPreferences";

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences preferences2;

        preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences2 = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME2, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);


    private void save() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();
        String eTextData = eText.getText().toString();
        preferencesEditor.putString(PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD, eTextData);
        preferencesEditor.commit();

        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor2 = preferences2.edit();
        String eTextData2 = eText2.getText().toString();
        preferencesEditor2.putString(PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD2, eTextData1);
        preferencesEditor2.commit();
    }



    private void read() {
        String textFromPreferences = preferences.getString(PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD, "");
        eText.setText(textFromPreferences);

        String textFromPreferences2 = preferences2.getString(PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD2, "");
        eText2.setText(textFromPreferences2);
    }
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Pls change the value of  PREFERENCES_NAME2 variable because it has same value as PREFERENCES_NAME.

Comment: why are you using two preference object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string have the same value:

```
private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "myPreferences";
private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME2 = "myPreferences";
```

so putString will override eachother.
Also you can use only 1 instance of SharedPreferences for both strings.

Comment: private static final String PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD = "textField";
    private static final String PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD2 = "textField";

---> i understand here also i need to change ?

Comment: @Rambo Yes you need to change them, there are unique keys. Let's say there are two people with name `Bob`, if you call `Bob` who should respond?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same preference file name `"myPreferences"`. Also, there is no need to use two different preferences, one is enough.

```
private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "myPreferences";

private SharedPreferences preferences;

preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);


private void save() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();
    String eTextData = eText.getText().toString();
    String eTextData2 = eText2.getText().toString();

   //Again, PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD and PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD2 should be //different

    preferencesEditor.putString(PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD, eTextData);
    preferencesEditor.putString(PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD2, eTextData2);
    preferencesEditor.commit();
}



private void read() {
    String textFromPreferences = preferences.getString(PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD, "");
    eText.setText(textFromPreferences);

    String textFromPreferences2 = preferences.getString(PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD2, "");
    eText2.setText(textFromPreferences2);
}
```

Comment: @Rambo You are welcome. What do you mean by ` I have enough reputation to give point `?

Comment: but in your way, i need to declaration 2x private static final String PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD = "textField"; ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is that your `PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD2` and `PREFERENCES_TEXT_FIELD` are equal.

Also, usually you don't need multiple instances of `SharedPreferences` unless you're loading for different configurations.